# If a Crossblooded Bloodrager chooses a Bloodline Familiar, from which bloodline does the familiar's additional ability originate?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, familiars, bloodline, bloodrager

A [Crossblooded](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/bloodrager/archetypes/paizo---bloodrager-archetypes/crossblooded-rager) [Bloodrager](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/bloodrager) selects two [bloodlines](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/bloodrager/bloodrager-bloodlines) at character creation and opts to forego his choice between either bloodline's 1st level power and instead gains a [bloodline familiar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/familiar#TOC-Bloodline-Familiars).

> Those with an inherent connection to magic often attract creatures who feel a similar instinctive pull toward magical forces. At 1st level, a sorcerer, bloodrager, or any other character with one of the following bloodlines can choose to gain a bloodline familiar. The character gains a familiar (as a wizard's familiar), treating her class level as her wizard level for the purposes of this ability. ***This familiar has an additional ability listed below based on the master's bloodline.***
>
> This replaces the 1st-level bloodline power granted by the character's bloodline; in addition, the character gains bonus spells from her bloodline one level later than she normally would. For example, a sorcerer with the aberrant bloodline who takes a bloodline familiar would not gain the acidic ray bloodline power, and she would gain her first bonus spell at 4th level, her second bonus spell at 6th level, and so on.
>
> GMs may use the following bloodline familiar abilities as written, or employ them as guidelines for devising bloodline familiar abilities for bloodlines not listed below.

Emphasis mine. Assume, just as an example, that this character chose the Arcane and Draconic bloodlines.

The Arcane ability is ***Spell Catalyst (Su)***:

> Spells you cast that target your familiar are treated as having a caster level 2 levels higher than your actual caster level.

The Draconic ability is ***Dragon's Flight (Ex)***:

> The familiar can sprout draconic wings, granting it a fly speed of 30 feet with average maneuverability for a number of minutes per day equal to 1/2 your caster level (minimum 1). These minutes need not be consecutive, but they must be spent in 1-minute increments. At 10th level, the familiar's fly speed increases to 60 feet with good maneuverability. At 20th level, the familiar's fly speed increases to 90 feet.

My question is this: **Which additional ability does the familiar have?**

Comment: Are you looking for a strict RAW reading or a rules interpretation? The latter seems pretty clear to me in this case, but the former might be undefined.

Comment: @ObliviousSage I would prefer a strict RAW answer if one is available, but since there might not be such an answer, I would accept a logical well thought out alternative. Obviously, if I had found the answer in the rules I wouldn't have asked the question, and I could just as easily guess or speculate as to what the answer is as anyone else; so any answer should have some kind of supporting evidence why it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You gain both as options, then you pick one of the two**

The Crossblooded Rager

> Bloodline Powers: At 1st, 4th, 8th, 12th, 16th, and 20th levels
>
> A crossblooded rager gains one of the two new bloodline powers available to him at that level. He can instead select a lower-level bloodline power he did not choose in place of one of these high-level powers.

Bloodline Familiar as you quoted:

> This replaces the 1st-level bloodline power granted by the character's bloodline;

The Bloodline Familiar replaces both 1st level Bloodline Powers on the two lists, but the Crossblooded Rager chooses one of the two options from both lists. At level 1 he picks one of the Bloodline Familiar powers, and then at level 4 he could choose one of his 4th level Bloodline Powers or the other 1st level Bloodline Familiar power from his other bloodline.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're saying would happen if the character chooses their other 1st-level bloodline power at 4th level? Do they get the power, does their familiar get the other familiar power, or do they get to choose?

Comment: It was an example use of the line:

"He can instead select a lower-level bloodline power he did not choose in place of one of these high-level powers."

At level one you pick one of the familiar powers, at level 4 you gain your next bloodline power. You can choose between the two level 4 powers provided by your bloodlines, or choose the remaining level 1 familiar power instead of a 4th level bloodline power.

Comment: So you're *not* arguing that at level 4 you could choose the other 1st level bloodline power and then trade that to give your familiar the other bloodline familiar power as well?

Comment: I'm saying regarding the 1st level bloodline power, there is nothing left to trade, if you choose the other 1st level bloodline power it IS the other bloodline familiar power.